# Weird behavior of QueryPerformanceCounter for measuring microseconds

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to measure the performance of my written function. As I can't use C++11 and I need microseconds, I used QueryPerformanceCounter from windows.h.

```
#include <Windows.h>
LARGE_INTEGER begin, end, frequency;

double timeElapsed = 0.0;

QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&begin);

    myFunctionToTest();

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);

    // get microsecs
    timeElapsed = ((end.QuadPart - begin.QuadPart) * 1000.0 / frequency.QuadPart) * 1000;

    std::cout << timeElapsed << std::endl;

    appendToCsvFile(timeElapsed);
}
```

The results of timeElapsed usually are between 2 and 10 microseconds if I do NOT call appendToCsvFile().

Calling the function appendToCsvFile(), which does nothing than writing the result to a file, hugely affects the result of the measurement (results between 20 and 60 microseconds).

**The function is called AFTER the measurement but it has some effect.** Is there any reason how this is possible? Is there any library for Visual C++ 2010 which is appropriate for microsecond measurements?

Comment: Without writing to file it's fast. With writing to file it's slow. Why do you need a special reason for this to happen? Am I missing something?

Comment: @anatolyg because starting and stopping the counters happens before calling the file operation.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing what happens in `myFunctionToTest()` and `appendToCsvFile()`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what happens if you add a `sleep(2000);` right after ` QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky it has a huge effect on the results. Same thing like calling my function `appendToCsvFile()`

Comment: File I/O on Windows is mostly buffered, so if you add an I/O operation you might pay the price sooner or later. Performance measurements on a multitasking OS are always noisy due other processes.

Comment: Expecting predictable delays on I/O is highly questionable.  In all likelihood you are actually measuring the perf of your installed anti-malware product :)  Profiling it just isn't very useful, you are not going to change your user's file system.

Comment: Without knowing, what `myFunctionToTest` actually does, there is little we can do to explain the observed behavior, outside listing the usual suspects.

Answer (score 2):

When measuring something in the microsecond range you need to expect weird things to happen.

There are many possible causes for this including:

1. CPU caches being cleared by `appendToCsvFile`, without this call `myFunctionToTest` is using the same memory over and over resulting in a nice warm cache and better performance.
2. When you write a file you trigger a whole series of actions which eventually result in the data ending up on your storage medium. Not all of these actions will be complete when control returns to your program resulting in extra background CPU usage which will slow down `myFunctionToTest`

Comment: You're doing it the right way, you just need to be aware when micro-benchmarking something that takes less than a millisecond that factors other than the efficiency of the code you are testing will affect execution time. If your real code is calling `appendToCsvFile` then you should leave it in as that is obviously affecting your execution time.

Comment: Thank you so far! I will just store my results in a vector and will write it to a file after the measurement. Should fix my problem.